# Visual Studio freezes when executing update-database in ASP.Net MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've trying to run an ASP.Net MVC app project locally, having received it from a friend.

However, if I execute the following in the package manager console:

```
update-database
```

Visual Studio freezes.

I'm running Visual Studio Professional 2015. Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

Any suggestions why/how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you got the project from your friend it should have some seeding in it. If you wrap the Seed method with try catch it should give what is failing during the Seed process.

Comment: There are two Seed methods but it appears as though neither are being hit as I've created a breakpoint in each at the top of the methods. Where should the Seed method be referenced?

Comment: It should be under Migrations and in Configuration.cs. If it is not giving any error then you should run the update-database with -script that will generate SQL script for whatever you are trying to update. Then copy and run it on your database. If it runs ok then it might be project permission issue. In that case move your project under c:/Your projects folder